# How to add a PX fallback to Zurb Foundation 4 REM function?

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, fallback

I am using this SCSS function from Zurb Foundation 4 framework:

```
@function remCalc($pxWidth) {
  @return $pxWidth / $em-base * 1rem;
}
```

it returns a REM value only, so it does not work with IE8. Is it possible to add a PX fallback to support IE8? I am not familiar in coding SASS functions.

Answer (score 3):

```
@mixin font-size($pxWidth){
  font-size:$pxWidth;
  font-size:remCalc($pxWidth);
}
.yourclass {
  @include font-size(16px); //outputs font-size:16px; font-size:1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as stated in the Foundation 4 Docs ie8 is not supported, see their extended article full a full explanation of why they do not support it any more.

If you are looking for IE8 support they recommend reverting back to Foundation 3.2

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/faq.html

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use a polyfill to enable rem support in IE8 and older.

I'm not sure which one, unfortunately. Try [html5shim](https://code.google.com/p/html5shim/) and [IE9.js](https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) for starters.

The function in question is a function, no a mixin. So it can't provide fallbacks. Consider writing your own mixin for that purpose. You can use [some hacks](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-specific-for-internet-explorer) to make a line of CSS work only for IE.

Comment: i want to avoid a polyfill or conditional loading of another stylesheet... i thought i can integrate the px fallback solution snook.ca html { font-size: 62.5%; } 
body { font-size: 14px; font-size: 1.4rem; } /* =14px */
h1   { font-size: 24px; font-size: 2.4rem; } /* =24px */ into the function...now i know it has to be a mixin